# full text search on a database using grep

Tags: linux, search, grep, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I used elasticsearch to implement a full text search in my web application. Is there a way we can use grep to perform a full text search on a database? Which is more efficient? Any resources to study about the advantages of one over the other would be helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well I think it will be possible depending upon your requirements of full-text search but it will take significant amount of work for you to implement it that way.

Elasticsearch uses tried and tested search algorithms and the efficient data structures for storage which makes search really really fast. But having said that, that does not say how fast it really is. It has tons of features that will allow you to build real-world search application rather easy - facets, aggregations, filters, support for multiple languages, highlighting, suggestions, etc. Companies of all scale are using elasticsearch for building search for their applications.

For your particular case, you will have to build your grep implementation and elasticsearch implementation and benchmark.

I can't help but say that there is not a lot you will be able to build with grep as compared to elasticsearch because:

- elasticsearch has a very rich set of queries that it supports, which are also very very easy to use - JSON and REST, its really simple.
- With grep, you will have to build complex patterns to be able to perform a search operation on your dataset. This will get even more complex when users will provide input and you will have to do the work of cleaning them and making a query out of it on-the-go.
- You will have to design data storage for efficient and fast search because you can't perform grep on the entire data set everytime someone performs search.